# How to find the change of basis matrix using inconvenient vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

I have the linear transformations T:
[Vector transformations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/726a0.png)

I know how to find the matrix that induces the transformation using the standard basis vectors (i.e. RREF the vectors = standard basis vector, and apply the transformation to them)

What I can't figure out is how to find the matrix using the change of basis matrix (i.e. find B in A = SBS^-1). When I was taught, I always used convenient vectors (on the plane or perpendicular to it), but never with other vectors

I know that for A = SBS^-1, S is
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & -2\\
    -1 & -1\\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
And S^-1 is
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1/3 & -2/3\\
    -1/3 & -1/3\\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

But I don't understand how to find B.

Would appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 1):

If you know $A$, $S$, $S^{-1}$ and are given $A = S B S^{-1}$, you can find $B$ by transforming both sides of the equation: left-multiply by $S^{-1}$ and right-multiply by $S$. You will obtain $ S^{-1} A S =  \underbrace{S^{-1} S}_{=I} B \underbrace{S^{-1} S}_{=I} = B$, which gives you $B$.

P.S. I hope this is what you were having a problem with (if I understood correctly).